# htaccess - Options FollowSymLinks or SymLinksIfOwnerMatch is off issue

Tags: apache, .htaccess, plesk

im using plesk for hosting my webpage. And evertime when im opening the root domain (e.G: "xxxxxx.xx"), my vServer is logging following error:

Options FollowSymLinks or SymLinksIfOwnerMatch is off which implies that RewriteRule directive is forbidden: /var/www/vhosts/xxxxxx.xx/httpdocs/index.pl

I do not have index.pl file in httpdocs. 
And this error occurs **not**, when i call "xxxxxx.xx/index.php" or other pages.

My htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^products/(.*)/(.*)/$ products.php?id=$1&p=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^static/(.*)/(.*)/$ static.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
```

Any ideas, how i can solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this may not sound right but in your plesk domain settings make sure cgi support is checked but perl support is unchecked. I could not get my 403 forbidden errors to go away when using mod_rewrite rules even with a modified Apache conf file. Once I unchecked the perl option in the plesk config for the domain perl rewrites work.